# Read address from MSI Capability Structure

Tags: drivers, pci

Is it possible to find the location of the MSI Capability Structure associated with a particular interrupt? Specifically, I need to know the PCI address that when written to, triggers that interrupt.

MSI interrupts can easily be initialize with the pci_alloc_irq_vectors(9) function, but this simply provides the irq number and no reference to the capability structure.

For reference, the capability structure is described in this document: https://pcisig.com/sites/default/files/specification_documents/msi-x_ecn.pdf

Comment: you can answer it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to be able to write that value yourself and generate an interrupt. That's not really how MSI works (though it might still be possible). With MSI (or MSI-X), you're basically programming the PCI device with an address to which it should generate a data write and a data value to write there when an interrupt is to be generated.

It's not guaranteed AFAIK that you can trigger the same interrupt yourself by writing to an address. Still, typically the address given in the MSI is a location within an address space controlled by the interrupt controller (which is usually implemented as a PCI device itself), and the data value tells the interrupt controller which interrupt to trigger. So in all likelihood, you could write the same value to the same physical memory address and so generate the same interrupt.

In any case, assuming you know which PCI device is generating the interrupt, you can go find the MSI capability structure and hence you could read back what it was programmed with. That's straightforward to do.

The PCI capabilities (which vary by device) are organized into a linked list within the device's configuration space. The start of the list is always given by the byte at offset 0x34 within the device configuration space. That byte value gives you the offset within the space of the first capability data structure.

Each capability consists of a one byte capability type ID, followed by a one byte "next capability" pointer, followed by varying-length data specific to the capability. So, starting from offset 0x34, you can hop through the capabilities.

To see this in action on any linux machine, you can run `lspci`. Giving it the `-v` flag (which can be repeated to get more and more detail) gives you an annotated view of the config space. You can also add `-xxxx` to get a complete hex dump of the config space, and so follow along the capability chain yourself. (BTW, you need to run it with `sudo` to get all the capability details.)

There are interfaces within the kernel that will do this for you: you can use `pci_find_capability` to find the offset of the capability you want. You can of course also find the capability yourself by starting with `pci_read_config_byte` with the offset 0x34, and following the list.

Once you've found the MSI capability, you then interpret its contents according to the document you cited above. You would use `pci_read_config_byte` (/`word`/`dword`) to access the parts of the capability data structure.

Comment: Yes this is possible when PCIe config space is mapped to the "common" memory space accessible to normal CPU instructions. This is not always the case, so generally it is not safe to assume one can get the "address" in PCIe config space. The API allows reading and writing the config space, but how it does this is hidden.

Comment: @ddbug Not sure what you're referring to here as "this". The MSI capability structure is always in the interrupting device's config space. There *is* an API for accessing that within the linux kernel, but yeah, it's not guaranteed to be directly accessible in memory space. But you don't need to access it via memory space. The MSI target address OTOH is not in config space. It must be in an address space to which the interrupting device can target a *memory write* transaction. It's just that it's not guaranteed (again, AFAIK) that you can write to the same location from the PCI host side.

Comment: You're right.    However, the OP asked about location of the capability struct in the config space, not about target address.

Comment: It's funny, the reason I need to find know the PCI address for the MSI is so I can tell the device to send a packet to that address. As far as the host is concerned, it should look identical to a normal MSI interrupt. I'm dealing with an engineering sample device that doesn't fully conform to PCI-SIG, so the jank is to be expected. In any case, thank you for the help. Oh, and the passing PCI_CAP_ID_MSI as the second argument to pci_find_capability gives the MSI/MSI-X capability structure.

Comment: @ddbug When I referred to the location of the capability structure, I was mostly referring to its offset in the config space of the device. I agree that an explicit address doesn't make much sense.